# Cannot use raster layers not defined as inputs in a model in QGIS 3.x

Tags: raster, qgis-3, raster-calculator, model

I have a problem in building raster models: both with QGIS 3.4.5 and QGIS 3.10.3, the raster calculator algorithm, used in a model, refuses to work if the requested layers are other than the defined raster layers as inputs.

The model is blocked with the following message:

```
An error occurred while performing the calculation
Error while running Raster calculator.
```

I'm looking for clear cuts in the forest with 2 satellite images n and n-1.

The model bug on the last algorithm (Raster calculator).

[image]
[image]